# Simple WinCE 5.0 application

Tags: windows-ce

I'm actually a web developer (PHP, Python), but now I need to make a *very* simple WinCE 5.0 application. Could you please suggest where I should start from? I'm probably not going to be a WinCE programmer, just need some really basic knowlodge.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Download eVC++ version 4 as well as the latest SP.

From there, install the WINCE 5.0 SDK.

That should give you enough to use the emulator.